# Chrome storage.get scope issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Call me a noob but I can't seem to get this to work:

```
var value = ""; // Tried this
function getKey(key) {
  var value = ""; // And this
  chrome.storage.local.get(key, function (data) {
    var value = data[key];
    console.log(value); // This prints the correct value
  });
  console.log(value); // But this will always print null
}
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `chrome.storage.local.get` call is asynchronous. The `getKey` function returns before the callback is executed, so the value isn't set.

In order to return the value in `getKey` you need to redefine like so:

```
function getKey(key, callback) {
  chrome.storage.local.get(key, function(data) {
    var value = data[key];
    callback(value); // This calls the callback with the correct value
  });
}
```

And your calls to `getKey` would appear like so:

```
getKey("some_key", function(value) {
  // do something with value
});
```

Comment: Just found out. Any hope I can get it to work synchronously? Or at least make sure getKey will return the value?

Comment: You have to call getKey asynchronously as well. Change the declaration to getKey(key, callback), and pass "value" to the callback rather than returning it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here. (1) A scope issue. (2) Asynchronous issue.
Try this:

```
// define getKey()
function getKey(key, callback) {
  chrome.storage.local.get(key, function (data) {
    callback(data[key]);
  });
}

// use getKey()
function setDocumentTitle(title) {
  document.title = title;
}

getKey('title', setDocumentTitle);
```